# Angular click event binding is not working properly

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to get relevant selections when radio button clicks. my relevant files are as below.

app.component.html

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
 <b>Select Catogory</b><br>
  <input type="radio" name="colors" [(ngModel)]="typing" (click)= "checktype(typing)" value="Agent">Agent<br>
  <input type="radio" name="colors" [(ngModel)]="typing" (click)= "checktype(typing)" value="Hospital" >Hospital
  <select>                                                                                                                                          
    <option [(value)]="agent" *ngFor="let agent of agents">{{agent}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
checktype(typing){
   console.log(typing)
   if(typing=="Agent"){
    this.agents=["amila","kasun", "ayesh"]
    console.log(typing)
  }else{
   this.agents=["hemas","general", "Asiri"]
   console.log(typing)
   }
  }
```

But when I click Agent radio button It display relevant data for Hospital radio button. I can't figure out what is the wrong with code. Any one can help me? Are there any mistakes done by me?

Comment: Please fix your indentation, your code as it stands is not readable.

Comment: can you explain `But when I click Agent radio button It display relevant data for Hospital radio button`

Comment: Could you try by giving local reference (#someName) to your radios and pass the value in the checktype function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `(click)` by `(ngModelChange)`

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vj2se5?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
<input type="radio" name="colors" [(ngModel)]="typing" (ngModelChange)= "checktype(typing)" value="Agent">Agent<br>
<input type="radio" name="colors" [(ngModel)]="typing" (ngModelChange)= "checktype(typing)" value="Hospital" >Hospital
```

Comment: You are welcome. I answered this first and then got 2 downvotes, not sure why the hatred!

Comment: Why use two-way data binding for input control at all? A simple solution would be to pass a custom value to the event handler, Something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8yd6jq?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use `change` event instead

```
<input type="radio" name="colors" [(ngModel)]="typing" (change)= "checktype(typing)" value="Agent">Agent<br>
  <input type="radio" name="colors" [(ngModel)]="typing" (change)= "checktype(typing)" value="Hospital" >Hospital
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a4px17)